# User as a subclass in Django

Tags: django, calendar

I'm working on a Django project for a medical team and have to include a calendar app to manage patients' appointments. Generally, a calendar is composed of several events with one or several attendees who are all Users. Here, attendees can be both doctors and patients. For practical and security reasons, they are separated in two different models: *auth.User* for medical staff, and *Patient* for the patients. My idea was therefore to create an abstract class called *People* on top of *User* and *Patient*:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DatetimeField()
    end = models.DatetimeField()
    #...

class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    people = models.ForeignKey(People)
    attendance = models.CharField(choices = ("Yes","No","Unknown"))

# Abstract class
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Patient is a subclass of People
class Patient(People):
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #...
```

Question is : How could I now make *Auth.User* also a subclass of *People* so that *User* could also be considered as attendees? Is it even possible? Otherwise how would you manage this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to turn things around, and inherit the medical staff model from [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) and from People, like so `class Staff(AbstractUser, People)`. This way, Staff has both the People model attributes and methods, and it still has the django User features.

Comment: I'm still wondering why I didn't think about multiple inheritance before... Anyway, thanks!